# multiple attribute selector on drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a drop down menu with multiple selections. Each has an option value. When three of these are selected, I'm supposed to have some text show up to the right of the box. So far, so good.

My problem is selecting ONLY those three to display text and the rest to display nothing. The problem is I can get two of them to work by using the `!== 'value1' && 'value2'`, but I have no idea the best way to select only these three.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<select id="award-type">
     <option value="">choose one</option>
     <option value="award1">Award 1</option>
     <option value="award2">Award 2</option>
     <option value="award3">Award 3</option>
     <option value="award4">Award 4</option>
     <option value="award5">Award 5</option>
     <option value="award6">Award 6</option>
</select>
  <div class="award-text"></div>
```

and the JS:

```
function dropDownSelect() {
    $('#award-type').on('change', function (e) {

        var selectValue = $(this).val();

        if (selectValue == 'award1') {
            $('.award-text').show().text("you won award 1");
        }
        if (selectValue == 'award2') {
            $('.award-text').show().text("you won award 2");
        }

        if (selectValue == 'award3') {
            $('.award-text').show().text("you won award 3");
        }
        else if (selectValue !== 'award1' && 'award2' && 'award3') {
            $('.award-text').show().text(" ");
        }

    });
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So this `select` should allow for multiple elements to be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly this condition is not a proper syntax**

```
selectValue !== 'award1' && 'award2' && 'award3'
```

supposed to be

```
selectValue !== 'award1' && selectValue !== 'award2' && selectValue !== 'award3'
```

Second why don't you write a simple `elseif` instead of multiple if statements

```
function dropDownSelect() {
    $('#award-type').on('change', function (e) {

        var selectValue = $(this).val(),
            $text = $('.award-text'); // cache selector
        if (selectValue == 'award1') {
            $text.show().text("you won award 1");
        } else if (selectValue == 'award2') {
            $text.show().text("you won award 2");
        } else if (selectValue == 'award3') {
            $text.show().text("you won award 3");
        } else {
            $text.hide();
        }
    });
}

$('#award-type').on('change', dropDownSelect).change();
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/cGGLb/)**

Comment: I like this solution, nice and compact.

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove the `function dropDownSelect()`
and replace it with `$(function() {`

And to solve the error, you have to do this:

`else if (selectValue != 'award1' && selectValue != 'award2' && selectValue != 'award3')`

**Here is the complete code**

```
$(function() {
  $('#award-type').on('change', function(e) {
   var selectValue = $(this).val();

   if (selectValue == 'award1') {
    $('.award-text').show().text("you won award 1");
   }else if (selectValue == 'award2') {
    $('.award-text').show().text("you won award 2");
   }else if (selectValue == 'award3') {
    $('.award-text').show().text("you won award 3");
   }else{
    $('.award-text').show().text(" ");
   }
  });
 });
```

Don't forget to include the jQuery library:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks for the help on the syntax. Just a question, why would changing the dropDownSelect() to simply (function() be an advantage? I'm just asking since the last place I worked this is the way I was told to write my functions since they usually had a ton of these per page and wanted it to be easy to maintain.

Comment: To begin the `jQUery` you need to start with `$(function() {`

If you still want to you use your function, you can do this:
Add the `function dropDownSelect() {` under `$(function() {` and
replace the last line with this:

    `}
     $('#award-type').on('change', dropDownSelect).change();
    });`

By doing this, every time the drop down select changes, it will trigger the `dropDownSelect` function.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for imparting some wisdom, that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you save yourself a world of pain and do this:

```
$('#award-type').change(function() {
    var award = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-award');
    $('.award-text').show().text( award ? "you won award "+award : '' );
});
```

... and change your HTML to include a data-award attribute on each option:

```
<select id="award-type">
    <option value="">choose one</option>
    <option value="award1" data-award="1">Award 1</option>
    <option value="award2" data-award="2">Award 2</option>
    <option value="award3" data-award="3">Award 3</option>
    <option value="award4" data-award="">Award 4</option>
    <option value="award5" data-award="">Award 5</option>
    <option value="award6" data-award="">Award 6</option>
</select>
<div class="award-text"></div>
```

Comment: I would, but I was told I can't alter the html, the PM said they don't want to involve the back-end guys if possible.

Comment: In that case I would either use a switch statement or you could use @Sushanth's answer with the else if statement

Comment: I did go with @Susanth's answer, although it would've been nice to use this if I could alter the HTML. It would really make the script a lot more compact. Thanks for the idea. Hopefully I can use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropDownSelect() {
    $('#award-type').on('change', function (e) {

        var selectValue = $(this).val();

        if (selectValue != 'award1') {
            $('.award-text').show().text("you won award 1");
        }
        if (selectValue == 'award2') {
            $('.award-text').show().text("you\ won award 2");
        }

        if (selectValue == 'award3') {
            $('.award-text').show().text("you won award 3");
        }
        else if (selectValue !== 'award1' && 'award2' && 'award3') {
            $('.awad-text').show().text(" ");
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest, for simplicity:

```
$('#award-type').change(function(){
    var self = $(this),
        opt = self.find('option:selected'),
        index = opt.index(),
        v = opt.text();

    self.next('.award-text').text(function(){
        return index > 0 && index < 4 ? 'You won ' + v : '';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Eww2q/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

### Try this: Its working fine:--

```
$('#award-type').on('change', function (e) {

var selectValue = $(this).val();
if (selectValue === 'award1' || selectValue ==='award2' || selectValue ==='award3') {

    $('.award-text').show().text($('#award-type :selected').text());
}
else {
    $('.award-text').show().text("nothing");
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a switch structure since you can play with multiple conditions (you can also join the cases and /or play with breaks) and you have also a -**default** case, exactly what you were looking for.

```
$('#award-type').change(function () {

    switch ($('#award-type').val()) {
            case "award1":
                $('.award-text').text("you won award 1");
                break;
            case "award2":
                $('.award-text').text("you won award 2");
                break;
            case "award3":
                $('.award-text').text("you won award 3");
                break;
            default:
                $(".award-text").text(" ");
        }
    return true;
    });
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/egorbatik/WGFNA/8/